# Make slots having unique pairs of numbers in the range 1..N

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, logic

There are *N* digits. Let say *N* = 6

This defines a range, starting from 1: [1,2,3,4,5,6]

I need to create their unique pairs such that each number in the range pairs up with another number only once.

For the example, the available pairs are:

```
(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),
(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),
(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),
(4,5),(4,6),
(5,6)
```

So we can say for a value of *N*, there will be *N*(N-1)/2* pairs.

For *N* = 6, the total number of pairs is 15.

Now, these pairs need to be put in slots, such that a slot will use numbers only once. Also, no pair can be used more than once.

Counter example:

```
Slot 1 - (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)
Slot 2 - (1,3),(2,4),(5,6) - This is a wrong slot as (5,6) is already used in Slot 1
Slot 2 - (1,3),(2,6),(4,5) - Correct
Slot 3 - (1,4),(2,5),(3,6)
Slot 4 - (1,5),(2,3),(4,6)
Slot 5 - (1,6),(2,4),(3,5)
```

There will be a total of *S* slots, where *S = N-1*.

Here, if *N* = 6, the number of slots = 6 - 1 = 5.

#### Problem

I couldn't find a pattern to create such slots.
I am looking for an algorithm for this. And if code is possible, I would prefer Python.

As of now, consider *N* to be even: 6, 8, 12, ...

Comment: [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) would definitely work, at least for small N. Fill subslots one by one, if at some point you cannot satisfy the constraints, undo the last choices first and choose different pairs.

Comment: Backtracking is working in case very small N. I need some other better way when N is more than 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a round robin tournament problem.

You can use the [circle method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Circle_method) to let everyone play any other member of the team (this is the pairing part) in several rounds (slots).

For n = 10, you would look at this snake-walk table:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  
10  9  8  7  6
```

The pairs of slot one are defined by the columns: (1, 10), (2, 9), (3, 8), (4, 7), (5, 6)

For the next slot, move all items in a "circle", except 1:

```
 1 10  2  3  4  
 9  8  7  6  5
```

Again, read out the pairs from the columns.

Next slot:

```
 1  9 10  2  3  
 8  7  6  5  4
```

... repeat until you are back to the configuration of the first slot.

As long as you apply this circle move consistently, it does not really matter with which configuration you start. Just keep one corner value fixed in place, while the other items circle around from slot to slot.

Here is an implementation:

```
def getslots(n):
    for round in range(1, n):
        yield [(1, round + 1)] + [
              tuple(sorted(
                  ((top+round) % (n - 1) + 2, 
                  (n - 3 + round - top) % (n - 1) + 2)
               )) for top in range(n//2 - 1)]
```

The `tuple` and `sorted` calls could be omitted if you don't care about the order of the two numbers in a pair.

Comment: This question was so hard for me to answer at least, next time please step in earlier :P
Also really nice compact code, so that's an upvote in my book.

Comment: Hats off... Perfect answer.. Thank you @trincot